# Why does this assignment inside a loop fail in Julia 0.7 and 1.0?

Tags: julia

```
(k, a, b, a1, b1) = (BigInt(2), BigInt(4), BigInt(1), BigInt(12), BigInt(4))

while k <= BigInt(4)
  (p, q, k) = (k*k, BigInt(2)*k+BigInt(1), k+BigInt(1))
end
```

This code compiles and runs in Julia 0.6, but in 1.0 produces `ERROR: UndefVarError: k not defined`.

Did something change between versions? What's wrong with this code in Julia 1.0?

Comment: As an aside, you don't need all those `BigInt` annotations everywhere. Due to automatic type promotion, you can just write: `while k <= 4
         p, q, k = k^2, 2k+1, k+1
       end`  and everything will be `BigInt`s.

Comment: Also, `big.((2, 4, 1, 12, 4))` should be more convenient than `(BigInt(2), BigInt(4), BigInt(1), BigInt(12), BigInt(4))`, with the same performance on version 0.7/1.0.

Comment: Sorry for the monologue, but I also want to point out that `BigInt(2)*k` is _slower_ than `2*k`, since the latter avoids allocating a second `BigInt`, and because there are special, faster, methods for ordinary non-big `Int`s multiplication with `BigInt`. The take-away is: always use integer literals if you can, they preserve types better across operations, and sometimes it's even faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer by [shadowtalker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2954547/shadowtalker) is correct. However, there is one important issue with this code that is worth adding some more explanation (and it was too long for a comment).

The relevant scoping rules in Julia for this case are the following (and if you want to read the details you can find them here https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/variables-and-scoping/#Local-Scope-1):

- `while` block introduces a new local scope;
- local scope inherits variables from enclosing global scope only for reading (unless they are qualified with `global` keyword as explained by [shadowtalker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2954547/shadowtalker));
- local scope inherits variables from enclosing local scope for reading and writing unless they are qualified with `local` keyword.

Now - why this is important? The reason is that your code will behave differently if you run it in global scope (e.g. in Julia REPL) and differently if you have it in a local scope (e.g. inside a function).

If you run it in global scope then what [shadowtalker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2954547/shadowtalker) showed is needed. However, if yourun it e.g. inside a function you do not have to change anything. For example this function will work correctly:

```
function f()
    (k, a, b, a1, b1) = (BigInt(2), BigInt(4), BigInt(1), BigInt(12), BigInt(4))

    while k <= BigInt(4)
      (p, q, k) = (k*k, BigInt(2)*k+BigInt(1), k+BigInt(1))
    end
end
```

also without creating a function if you e.g. use `let` block in a global scope the code will just run as intended:

```
let
    k, a, b, a1, b1 = BigInt(2), BigInt(4), BigInt(1), BigInt(12), BigInt(4)

    while k <= BigInt(4)
      (p, q, k) = (k*k, BigInt(2)*k+BigInt(1), k+BigInt(1))
    end

    k, a, b, a1, b1
end
```

because `let` creates a local scope (I have added the statement at the end of `let` block to make it evaluate to the values of the introduced variables so that you can inspect them).

This is a significant change from Julia 0.6 and earlier where Julia made a difference between hard and soft local scopes (see here https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.6/manual/variables-and-scoping/#scope-of-variables-1), but this distinction is gone - all local scopes now behave identically. This is a significant change an in practice it means that you can expect that the code that runs correctly inside some local scope (a function in most cases) will change its behavior if you copy-paste it to a global scope. From my experience using `let` blocks as shown above is the simplest way alleviate this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, something changed. I *think* this is what's going on:

Assigning to `p`, `q`, and `k` inside the loop does actually creates new `p`, `q`, and `k` bindings in a new local scope. Then, because `k` is also used on the right-hand side, Julia tries to use the *local* `k` and fails.

In order to obtain the expected semantics (mutating the existing `p`, `q`, and `k` defined at the top level), you need to declare them "global" first:

```
while k <= BigInt(4)
  global p, q, k

  (p, q, k) = (k*k, BigInt(2)*k+BigInt(1), k+BigInt(1))
end
```

edit: thanks to user AnAverageHuman on Freenode for figuring this out.