# Julia Variable scope

Tags: scope, migration, julia

I'm trying to use some global variables (m, n, r) in a while loop, but julia 1.0.0 is telling me that those variables aren't defined. The code works with julia 0.7.0, with some warnings.
This is the code I'm using (yes, it's poorely written, I hope this is not the problem. I removed a `println` statement for the sake of simplicity):

```
m = readline()
n = readline()
m = parse(Int, m)
n = parse(Int, n)
r = m % n
while (r > 0)
        println( "m: $(m) n: $(n) r: $(r)" )
        r = m % n
        m = n
        n = r
end
```

This is the results with julia 1.0.0:

```
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: m not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at euclide.jl:11 [inlined]
 [2] top-level scope at ./none:0
 [3] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
 [4] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
 [5] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
 [6] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:229
 [7] _start() at ./client.jl:421
in expression starting at euclide.jl:10
```

And with julia 0.7.0:

```
┌ Warning: Deprecated syntax `implicit assignment to global variable `r``.
│ Use `global r` instead.
└ @ none:0
┌ Warning: Deprecated syntax `implicit assignment to global variable `m``.
│ Use `global m` instead.
└ @ none:0
┌ Warning: Deprecated syntax `implicit assignment to global variable `n``.
│ Use `global n` instead.
└ @ none:0
```

The code works with julia 0.7.0, but why doesn't it work with version 1.0.0 ?

Answer (score 4):

You have to declare variables you define in global scope and *assign to* in loop local scope as `global` inside the loop like this:

```
m = readline()
n = readline()
m = parse(Int, m)
n = parse(Int, n)
r = m % n
while (r > 0)
        println( "m: $(m) n: $(n) r: $(r)" )
        global r = m % n
        global m = n
        global n = r
end
```

The reason you have to do it is that `while` loops introduce a new local scope, so without `global` keyword assignment like `m = n` tells Julia that `m` is a local variable inside a `while` loop so then in the line `println( "m: $(m) n: $(n) r: $(r)" )` Julia decides that `m` is yet undefined.

See also https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/variables-and-scoping/ and [Why does this assignment inside a loop fail in Julia 0.7 and 1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51814689/why-does-this-assignment-inside-a-loop-fail-in-julia-0-7-and-1-0/51816822) for further explanation of the scoping rules in Julia.