# Why still fails local/global scope in interactive julia session?

Tags: scope, julia

I just recently moved to Julia 1.1 `Version 1.1.0 (2019-01-21)`, but I think this is an issue from also 1.0 as reported [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/28750). For summing up a dummy variable, an error arises:

```
julia> a = 0.0
0.0
for i in 1:10
       a += 1
end
ERROR: UndefVarError: a not defined
```

Now, forcing the scope of the variables:

```
julia> local a
julia> for i in 1:10
       a += 1
       end
ERROR: UndefVarError: a not defined
```

either doing `global a` returns the same error. What is now the solution?

More: uhmm also doing the `let .. end` [trick](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/28523) does not return the correct value

```
julia> let a = 0.0;
     for i in 1:10
       a+= 1
     end
     end

julia> a
0.0
```

EDIT: Notice that this is only in the REPL and NOT in jupyter or in a script. The error does not arises in the last two cases.

Comment: This is not a bug. This famous scope behavior did not change in v1.1. `let` block does work except that the `a` in the `let` block is a new binding that is not your global `a` and does not outlive the local scope introduced by `let`. If you would like to use `a` in the `let` block, you need to use it before ending the `let` or store the local `a` somewhere outside.

Comment: I didn't say it was a bug... Also I would not label the question as duplicate, since this is in REPL and not in a script or in the notebook, where things works fine.

Comment: REPL and script have the same behavior. Jupyter Notebook has a different behavior only if you have SoftGlobalScope.jl package loaded (which is the default). Actually if you load this package in REPL you can get the same behavior as in Jupyter Notebook (see the docs of the package).

Comment: @hckr, not sure this counts as a duplicate, since the question and answer in your linked post both pertain to pre-1.0 behavior, which of course was different from what we have now.

Comment: @CameronBieganek The questions about the global scope issue have been asked and answered multiple times. You can see a few [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930537/scope-of-variables-in-julia) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52122233/julia-variable-scope). That said, I think the question is a duplicate, although I failed to refer to the right question when marking it as a duplicate.

Comment: @hckr Thanks for the new links. This is definitely a duplicate. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the `a` inside the `for` loop to be a global variable:

```
julia> a = 0
0

julia> for i in 1:10
           global a += 1
       end

julia> a
10
```

Comment: Uhmm yes, I just saw this exactly [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Julia/comments/9vxkw6/weird_behaviour_with_for_loops/).